# Embed dozens of comments from Facebook's iframes on a website

Tags: facebook, iframe, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-iframe

I'm trying to embed few dozens of comments into my own website. I'm currently using [this method](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-comments/).

The problem is that the pages loads really slow (takes a few minutes to load all comments when there are few dozens of comments).

How can I present dozens of facebook comments on my website without it taking so long to show up?

Comment: You're doing each one via an href with its url? Seems like using an api and writing JS would be hugely more efficient than making dozens of requests. How are you getting the urls now?

Comment: Like described in the [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/embedded-comments/) I provided in the question - I'm getting the url code by clicking the date of the comment and then copying in to a iframe tag in my website.

Comment: So you're making dozens of requests--this takes time. This is for specific comments, not groups of them. I'd recommend an API approach instead.

Comment: I couldn't find any API approach to show specific comments (from various posts), are you sure there's such an option?

Comment: ¯\_(ツ)_/¯ No clue; haven't coded against FB for 5+ years now. But if you want any sort of performance that's what you'll need. If they're not dynamic you could retrieve them off-line or in a web worker or something.